# Docker compose service ports not reachable from host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to deploy my docker-compose file V3 in a swarm by following the gettings started guide from Docker on [Docker Get Started, Part 3: Services](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/).

Somehow, I am not able to reach my application on port 8081, if I call: `docker service ls` I receive the following info:

```
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                        PORTS
35q1szvf30fq        deckin_node1        replicated          1/1                 repo_name/deckin:0.1   *:8081->8080/tcp
```

This means that my service is running and reachable through port 8081. However, if I call `docker ps` I receive the following:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
665f8f29fc2d        repo_name/deckin:0.1   "./app"                  15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       8080/tcp            deckin_node1.1.ok89w9iz6tkjsiktbw2euhs1q
```

As you can see, port 8081 is not mapped to port 8080, and I therefor cannot reach my service from my host machine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here are 2 possible causes. 

1)  container is not staying alive, you can check that by command docker service ps (service name) if you see any shutdown or exit containers that's image problem
2)may be firewall problem in your host or try to access swarm cluster worker nodes, not manager node.

Comment: Docker service ps deckin_node1 shows that the service is running, what do you exactly mean with your second question?

Comment: how many nodes in docker swarm cluster.  and what error exactly you'r getting

Comment: One, I'm not getting an error, somehow my ports are just not reachable from host

Comment: Your results command are normal.
If you try to access to your service outside of your swarm network you have to use http://127.0.0.1:8081.
If you try to access inside your network (in other service), you have to use http://deckin_node1:8080

Comment: Ah, that was the trick, I tried localhost:8081 (that worked when I used docker-compose v2). Is this a default setting for swarm networks?